How can I adjust exposure/brightness for DJI P4M images taken in auto exposure mode
I've taken drone imagery over a lake on auto exposure mode. However, as i want to stitch the images to make a mosaic, and they have different exposures, when stitched next to one another they don't look consistent/uniform. How can I adjust the exposure to bring to one so it looks like one consistent image rather than the 16 or so that they are?

What is the software you use to edit the images?

I was using GIMP however, the main purpose of these images is to load them on ArcGIS Pro (which has a function that is able to place the images over their recorded GPS locations) for remote sensing purposes. I loaded them into the software however they aren't showing and i suspect thats because exifdata is missing? GPS data is still there, and the software pinpoints where each image was taken but the actual image doesn't show. I tried some python scripts to adjust the images using PIL but it after adjusting the exposure, the process was somehow removing GPS exifdata.
